# Run 2 applications on startup without runnning the explorer

Tags: windows-10, register

I'm fairley new to this. I would like to run two applications on windows 10 once it starts up but without running the explorer or any other application.
I have tried using `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\shell` but it only works with the first application. 
I would appreciate any help offered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the desktop icon to the folder that is accessible from  **shell:startup**.

First Do:

**Windows Key + R**

You should get the Run prompt

Enter **shell:startup** and press **Enter**

You should get to a directory and see a couple desktop icons

Copy the desktop icon of the applications you plan to start there and close the window.

On your next reboot, the applications should start without any actions.

Here's an example of my setup:

[Example of shell:startup setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrqJY.png)

Comment: Do you mean that the icon should be copied, or the shortcut? The icon is just a picture that is usually applied to the shortcut. Could you perhaps edit this answer to clarify this point?

Comment: This will run on login. How does that conform to the requirement not to run Explorer?

Comment: It will never open up windows explorer, it will just run the applications that have been dropped in that folder

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the Windows Task Scheduler (`taskschd.msc`).

Start it up, create a task, specify mode, define the trigger as "At startup"
and the Action as running your program(s).

Note : The program(s) in question must not have a GUI that requires user action.

For more information, see for example :

- [Windows 7: Task - Create to Run a Program at Startup and Log On](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/67503-task-create-run-program-startup-log.html)
- [How to Enable Programs and Custom Scripts to Run at Boot](https://www.howtogeek.com/138159/how-to-enable-programs-and-custom-scripts-to-run-at-boot/)